# Why didn't God just create heaven?

Tags: shiva, krishna, creation, heaven

I am pretty sure there would have been enough sports in heaven why create anything else why didn't just create youth and happiness?

Comment: The reason is that some jiva atma's for some reason did not want to stay with god.

Comment: Are we all that Jiva atma?@Wikash_

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: i asked why do some jiva atma doesn't want to stay with god because of maya? Are we all that jiva atma that doesn't want to stay with god and finding our way back? ARe all jiva atma different in nature?@Wikash_

Comment: It could be for a variety of reasons. Some are just curious, some want to help the avatars descending upon earth, some want to help others go back to god, etc.